# How to make a pulldown menu that acts on a selected element?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

## TL;TR

How do I:

```
getMyComponent(selectedMyComponentID).complexOperation()
```

To me this sounds like such a trivial and useful thing, e.g. from a pulldown menu.

## A little more detail

Assume I'm making an editor of some kind (think todo-list or something). The GUI has the concept of a "selected" element. (In our real case it is the currently visible [bootstrap nav-tab](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#tabs)), and I want to have pull-down menus with menu-items that perform different operations on the selected element.

Assuming I have the id of the "selected" component, getting a reference to the MyComponent that has a `complexOperation()` method corresponding to the id is surprisingly difficult.

Perhaps that is because I'm not doing this "the Vue way".

I see these ways to accomplish `complexOperationOnSelectedMyComponent()`:

- use [ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref)s - seems messy and ugly
- refactor the `complexOperation()` out of MyComponent and into a new MyData, so the business logic on the data is used by oth App.vue and MyComponent.vue. Now the parent is changing data and therefore props - sounds vue-ish. But that leads to lots of boilerplate since every operation in every component now  has two versions. I'm not a fan of boilerplate and duplication...
- use vuex? I think I'm not there yet...
- Use an "event bus" Vue instance and $emit events from parent to child. Seems overkill. And is messy and has boilerplate.

Am I missing something? Isn't this pretty standard stuff?

## Details

For simplicity, we'll say that there is a template:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div v-for="elem in mydata" :key="elem.id" @click="setSelected(elem)">
      <MyComponent :value="elem"/>
    </div>
    <button @click="complexOperationOnSelectedComponent">
        Complex operation on Selected Component
    </button>
  </div>
</template>
```

and a data structure where the first one is initially selected:

```
data() {
  return {
    mydata: [
      { id: 0, foo: "bar", selected: true },
      { id: 1, foo: "baz", selected: false },
      { id: 2, foo: "world", selected: false }
    ]
  };
}
```

(Complete [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/button-onclick-on-selected-child-rnp80))

So there is a "Complex operation on Selected Component" button. But what should I put in the `complexOperationOnSelectedComponent` method?

The codesandbox above also has equivalent buttons inside each MyComponent. They simply call a `complexOperation()` method in the MyComponent definition.

I'm thinking that whether the button happens to be inside or outside the component is a minor detail. Get a reference to the MyComponent for the selected id and call `selectedComponent.complexOperation()` in the menu item's `@click` handler.

In our real scenario, the user selects the "component" by clicking on a nav-bar, (not on the MyComponent instance), so what we have is a id (`mydata[n].id` or 0, 1 or 2 above).

### Using ref-s

What I could do was put `ref="components"` in the `<MyComponents>` definition. Because it is in a `v-for` loop, `this.$refs.components` will then be an array of `MyComponents`. Find the one with the right id and use it.

Because there is no guarantee about the order of in `this.$refs.components` I'd have to search the array for the selectedMyComponentID every time, but hey...

Is this really the best solution?

Comment: You can bind a dynamic ref and use the selected component's id, like `:ref="'mycomponents' + elem.id"`

Comment: Thanks, that works better than my `ref="components"` solution even if `this.$refs.mycomponents1` is still an array with a single element.

Comment: There is a similar discussion: [Communicate from parent to child - General Discussion - Vue Forum](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/communicate-from-parent-to-child/66741)

Answer (score 0):

You typically want to use $refs if you need access to the DOM directly to get to elements that are not connected/controlled to any Vue instance properties.
You can store which element is selected in data and target that specific element.

Putting your method in the parent or the child? It depends, do you need the logic in other places? In this case, I think it makes sense in the child because you want to be able to perform actions there as well.

```
Use an "event bus" Vue instance and $emit events from parent to child. Seems overkill.
```

Props go from parent to child. Events are emitted from child to parent.
Vuex and event busses are really helpful in larger applications but really not needed in this case. You should, however, emit changes that you want to make to your props and not edit them directly like you are doing now in MyComponent.

I refactored your code a bit, I do want to repeat that modifying the values of props directly is bad practice: https://codesandbox.io/s/button-onclick-on-selected-child-lf37c?fontsize=14

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div v-for="elem in mydata" :key="elem.id" @click="selectedElem = mydata[elem.id]">
      <MyComponent :value="elem" :reverse="elem.reverse"/>
    </div>
    <button @click="reverseSelectedFoo">Reverse Selected Foo</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import MyComponent from "./components/MyComponent";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    // Ideally this data is read from an API somewhere
    return {
      mydata: [
        { id: 0, foo: "bar", reverse: false },
        { id: 1, foo: "baz", reverse: false },
        { id: 2, foo: "world", reverse: false }
      ],
      selectedElem: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    reverseSelectedFoo() {
      this.selectedElem.reverse = !this.selectedElem.reverse;
    }
  },
  components: {
    MyComponent
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I explicitly called the operation `complexOperation()` to hint that it couldn't be modelled as the flip of a single boolean key in the object. I want the logic to live in a My(Component|Data|Whatever) specific object. I don't want the parent to know about the inner workings of that sub-domain. And if MyComponent can't modify *any* of the data in the props it is given, then, oh my... Won't all the logic of the application end up living in the top App.vue if I take this to heart?

Comment: And if this "don't modify inside props" at all is really true, then where would I _ever_ use `v-model` outside of Hello World tiny demos, assuming the state of the application is useful and needs to be saved at some point?

Comment: I explicitly called the operation complexOperation() to hint that it couldn't be modelled as the flip of a single boolean key in the object: Okay but I can only go by the code you provided. If you have a function in your myComponent that needs to be called in reaction to user interaction you have to tell your component. How you do that is up to you. In your example it's a boolean but you can pass anything.

Comment: In any application that is slightly larger than a Hello World demo, it would be really problematic to directly mutate the parent’s state, because it makes it almost impossible to debug. A good way to deal with `v-model` and props is to initialize a property in your component to the prop and bind `v-model` to the local property. Then you can `$emit` it back to the parent.